# Introduction to discrete subgroups of the euclidean group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

I am looking for a general introduction to discrete subgroups of the euclidean group (= group of isometries in euclidean space).

Even though I searched quite a bit, I was unable to find a good introduction.

Any hints for which book or survey to look?

Comment: Does something like $\mathbf{x}\mapsto\mathbf{x}+n\mathbf{a}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ fit the bill?

Comment: @Dan: Sorry but I'm not sure what you mean. Are you asking if the set $\{ x \mapsto x + na \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a discrete subgroup? If so, the answer is no since it's not even a group if $a \neq 0$. If you take all integers instead of natural numbers, it will become a discrete subgroup though.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant the integers but for some reason typed $\mathbb{N}$. I thought you were after an example but I see you're after a more general introduction.

Comment: Try the book *Finite Reflection Groups* by Grove and Benson.

Comment: @lhf: Thanks for the hint but I this book is too specific. It only covers finite groups (which are trivially discrete subgroups) and mostly only very specific ones (namely Coxeter groups). But I agree that for these groups it is a neat introduction.

Comment: Two keywords you might want to try "Bieberbach theorem" and "space form."

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the book by Conway, Burgiel, and Goodman-Strauss entitled "The symmetries of things". Although I have not looked at the book myself, I know Conway to be an entertaining author, and the table of contents seems to cover a wide range of topics regarding discrete subgroups of isometries of Euclidean spaces and of other spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in dimensions 2 and 3, consider reading "[Geometries and Groups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540152814)" by Nikulin and Shafarevich.

If you are interested in higher dimensional groups as well, Wolf's "[Spaces of constant curvature](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821852825)," covers basics (and much more).